# Always prompts "sh: line 1: --: command not found" when running kubectl exec command in php exec

Tags: php, shell, kubernetes

I got stuck by the following error message when I tried to execute kubectl exec command in php exec.

```
error: you must specify at least one command for the container
sh: line 1: --: command not found
```

Here is the command:

```
$kube_cmd = "sudo kubectl exec -n=ns-abc pod-abc -- cat /etc/hosts";
exec($kube_cmd);
```

and then in httpd error log file, can find following:

```
error: you must specify at least one command for the container
sh: line 1: --: command not found
```

Looks like php exec cannot recognize -- ? because if I remove -- or run other commands without --, the error disappeared.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Does the command work outside of php?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What is your kurbernetes version? If I remember well, the -- wasn't necessary before

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, the command works outside of PHP. Kubernetes version is 1.2. `BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z"`. I will provide a reproducible example shortly.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I found the cause when I tried to provide a reproducible example. Originially I used this command `$kube_cmd = "sudo kubectl exec -n=$namespace $podname -- cat /etc/hostname"`. After I corrected it like this, the issue is gone. `$kube_cmd = "sudo kubectl exec -n=".$namespace." ".$podname." -- cat /etc/hostname"`. It is a basic PHP syntax issue :(

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` to run `kubectl` commands, and its command handling may lead to a problem like this.  The command from your last comment is especially dangerous: it is vulnerable to a [shell injection attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection) where if the caller controls the `$namespace` variable they can run any command they want.